# Python itertools all permutations of a list with repeated elements

Tags: python, permutation, python-itertools

I'm wanting to generate all permutations of a list that contains repetitions.

A naive approach might be to use itertools.permutations, but permutations doesn't care about elements being repeated:

```
for j in itertools.permutations([0,1,1]):
    print(j)

                  
(0, 1, 1)
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
```

So instead of 3 elements we get 6.

You could track the elements it's producing and discard repetitions. But it's easier to do it with product and discard ones that don't conform to the original shape:

```
for j in itertools.product([0,1],repeat=3):
    if sum(j)!=2: continue
    print(j)

                  
(0, 1, 1)
(1, 0, 1)
(1, 1, 0)
```

This is the desired output, but does itertools support this more naturally? Obviously, this could get computationally intense for bigger lists.

Comment: Dedupe the list first?

Comment: you can put all results in `set()` and you get unique results. OR in `for`-loop you can check if you already have result in `set()` and skip it - and if you don't have it then put it in `set()`.

Comment: Thanks all. Deduping is easy enough. The challenge is to reduce the size of the generator but only producing each element once. But it looks like itertools is not the answer for this, at least not natively. A recursive function would work quite well I think

Comment: But the sympy multiset is the answer I was looking for. Good to know that little piece of terminology!